# how to load complete UIView before web service is call

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In my project there is left & right slide menu,so if i tap on left menu's cell one `UIViewController` is call in this `UIViewControllers viewDidLoad` method.

i am calling SOAP based web service.
So my question is when i tap on `UITableViewCell`.**view is not getting fully loaded in to screen it is stuck at there. and view is fully load and i can see on full display when data comes from web service.**

so i have to wait for data come than i can see whole `UIView`.
**So how to load `UIViewController` at first tap?** and after `UIView` is appear i will put activity indicator that's why user can see at least data is loading in `UIView`.

Thanks in advance please any one can help me to get out of this problem.

**Edit:I have tried to call web service method to `viewWillAppear`**

Comment: use background threading

Comment: Don't call web service within `viewDidLoad`, put it in `viewDidAppear`, and use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue()` for web service call

Comment: can u post your code ,so we can get more clear understanding

Comment: i already call within `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^` for async call.

Comment: @ViralSavaj Ahem, web services calls on main thread are **really** not a good idea.

Comment: yup i had already tried out calling web service from viewDidAppear.

Comment: code for now: `-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self callWebService];
}` and in web service method `
 response = [binding Index_global:request];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSString *responseString = [self getDataFromWebServiceResponse:response];
        if (responseString!=nil)
        {
            [self processData:responseString];
        }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)performBackgroundTask
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //Do background work   (call your Web service method here)
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //Update UI
        });
    });
}
```

Call Webservice in Background work and use main queue for loading Tableview

Comment: Accept the answer if you find it useful

Comment: from where to perform this background task?within web service call?

Comment: check my answer again

Comment: call this performBackgroundTask in viewdidload

Answer (score 0):

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad]; 

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

    //Call ur web service in view did load or appear and add data in datsource of tableview

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //table view reload data
    });

});

}
```

Comment: the above answer is accepted,if u see properly .dont just downvote any answer just for  fun.its just we both answered at sametime